# How can I get a text field in the mobile app to allow large entries of text

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to setup a custom screen in the mobile app, and there are a few things that are still a mystery.

One of them is how to get a PXTextEdit field to show multiple lines, or even allow entry into that field without it just highlighting the field and no way to add to it.

The other is how to add a Rich Text control to the mobile app ala the Cases screen.  I've tried using the code to add it the way the Cases screen does.  I have a PXRichTextEdit field, called 'Details', but this doesn't show up on the mobile app at all:

```
  add field "Details" {
  textType = HTML
}
```

In this context:

```
add screen AC503000 {
add container "MeetingAgenda" {
add field "MeetingID"
add field "Subject"
add field "Status"    
add field "MeetingDate"    
add field "MeetingTime"    
add field "Details" {
  textType = HTML
}
add recordAction "Save" {
  behavior = Save
}    
add recordAction "Cancel" {
  behavior = Cancel
}
add recordAction "Delete" {
  behavior = Delete
}
```

}

I've also tried to add a container called "Details" since this shows up in the WSDL file, and that shows a menu item, but takes you nowhere, and sends the app into a tailspin where it can't recover and has to be restarted.

At this point I'm lost as to how to do these two things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable multiline mode, use

```
add field "Details" { textType = PlainMultiLine }
```

To show your `PXRichTextEdit` field try to use {Container Name}#{Field Name} from the WSDL

```
add field "Details#Details" { textType = HTML }
```